# Monitoring DB queries invocation performance

Tags: grafana, promql

I have integrated micrometer in my spring-boot project. I have scrapping this data in the Prometheus server to draw graphs. I am new to Grafana and I want how know how to query **gauge** and **summary** types and how to draw graphs (time-series, gauge), I should you to monitor my application's performance. What this numeric value represent which is showing after '}'.

```
# HELP spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max Duration of repository invocations
# TYPE spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max gauge
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_max{application="customer",exception="None",method="save",repository="InfoRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 0.004128917

# HELP spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds Duration of repository invocations
# TYPE spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds summary
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{application="customer",exception="None",method="save",repository="InfoRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 42998.0
spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{application="customer",exception="None",method="save",repository="InfoRepository",state="SUCCESS",} 53.740906851
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numeric value after metric is metric's value.

For metrics of type *gauge* it's current value as is. For metrics of type *counter* it's value of counter, and it's usually not interesting by itself, but we are more interested in it's increase or rate over time:

```
increase(http_requests_total [1h])
rate(node_cpu_second_total [5m])
```

Metrics of type summary consist of three time series:

- streaming φ-quantiles (0 ≤ φ ≤ 1) of observed events, exposed as `<basename>{quantile="<φ>"}` (missing in your example)
- the total sum of all observed values, exposed as `<basename>_sum`
- the count of events that have been observed, exposed as `<basename>_count`.

`<basename>_count` always behaves as counter internally, while `<basename>_sum` might not if observations might have negative values. [Official documentation on matter](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/histograms/#count-and-sum-of-observations).

To visualize your *summary* you can use query like mentioned in the linked documentation:

```
  rate(spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum[5m])
/
  rate(spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count[5m])
```